# Nextcloud: upload large files

Tags: php, apache, upload, large-files, nextcloud

I have a Nextcloud 18 on Apache/PHP 7.3, behind a reverse proxy (out of my control).

On an upload of large files (over 2-3GB) the upload breaks, but only **SOMETIMES!**

On the client (browsers web-dev console) I get:

```
[Error]  (3)
{type: "fileuploadfail", timeStamp: 1615985108652, jQuery21408983418735326512: true, target: <input id="file_upload_start">, isTrigger: 3, …}
{classes: {}, disabled: false, create: null, dropZone: m, replaceFileInput: true, …}
undefined
                fail (merged-index.js:2510)
                _trigger (main.js:578:7683)
                _onFail (merged-index.js:9608)
                (anonyme Funktion) (main.js:578:1098)
                (anonyme Funktion) (merged-index.js:9642)
                u (main.js:25:22825)
                fireWith (main.js:25:23632)
                (anonyme Funktion) (merged-index.js:9539)
                u (main.js:25:22825)
                fireWith (main.js:25:23632)
                x (main.js:25:70964)
                (anonyme Funktion) (main.js:25:74456)
 
https://<NEXTCLOUD.DOMAIN>/remote.php/dav/uploads/<MY_USER_NAME>/web-file-upload-1234567/98765432

[Error] Failed to load resource: Die Netzwerkverbindung wurde unterbrochen (The network connection was interrupted). (996147200, line 0)
 
[Info] OC.requestToken changed – "<REQUEST_TOKEN>" (main.js, line 148)
```

The Apache Webserver / PHP logs this Error:

```
{
"Exception":"Sabre\\\\DAV\\\\Exception\\\\BadRequest",
"Message":"Expected filesize of 10485760 bytes but read (from Nextcloud client) 
and wrote (to Nextcloud storage) 4571136 bytes. 
Could either be a network problem on the sending side or a problem writing 
to the storage on the server side.",
"Code":0,
"Trace": [
{
"file":"/nextcloud/apps/dav/lib/Connector/Sabre/Directory.php",
"line":156,
"function":"put",
"class":"OCA\\\\DAV\\\\Connector\\\\Sabre\\\\File",
"type":"->",
"args":[null]
},
{
"file":"/nextcloud/apps/dav/lib/Upload/UploadFolder.php",
"line":47,
"function":"createFile",
"class":"OCA\\\\DAV\\\\Connector\\\\Sabre\\\\Directory",
"type":"->",
"args":["985661440",null]},
{
"file":"/nextcloud/3rdparty/sabre/dav/lib/DAV/Server.php",
"line":1096,
"function":"createFile",
"class":"OCA\\\\DAV\\\\Upload\\\\UploadFolder",
"type":"->",
"args":["985661440",null]
},
{
"file":"/nextcloud/3rdparty/sabre/dav/lib/DAV/CorePlugin.php",
"line":525,
"function":"createFile",
"class":"Sabre\\\\DAV\\\\Server",
"type":"->",
"args":["uploads/<MY_USERNAME>/web-file-upload-<FILE_ID>/985661440",null,null]
},
{"function":"httpPut",
"class":"Sabre\\\\DAV\\\\CorePlugin",
"type":"->",
"args":[{"absoluteUrl":"https://<NEXTCLOUD.DOMAIN>/remote.php/dav/uploads/<MY_USERNAME>/web-file-upload-<FILE_ID>/985661440",
"__class__":"Sabre\\\\HTTP\\\\Request"}
,
{"__class__":"Sabre\\\\HTTP\\\\Response"}]},
{
"file":"/nextcloud/3rdparty/sabre/event/lib/EventEmitterTrait.php",
"line":105,
"function":"call_user_func_array",
"args":[
[
{
"__class__":"Sabre\\\\DAV\\\\CorePlugin"},
"httpPut"
],
[
{
"absoluteUrl":"https://<NEXTCLOUD.DOMAIN>/remote.php/dav/uploads/<MY_USERNAME>/web-file-upload-<FILE_ID>/985661440",
"__class__":"Sabre\\\\HTTP\\\\Request"
},
{
"__class__":"Sabre\\\\HTTP\\\\Response"
}
]
]
},
{
"file":"/nextcloud/3rdparty/sabre/dav/lib/DAV/Server.php",
"line":479,
"function":"emit",
"class":"Sabre\\\\Event\\\\EventEmitter",
"type":"->",
"args":["method:PUT",
[
{
"absoluteUrl":"https://<NEXTCLOUD.DOMAIN>/remote.php/dav/uploads/<MY_USERNAME>/web-file-upload-<FILE_ID>/985661440",
"__class__":"Sabre\\\\HTTP\\\\Request"},
{"__class__":"Sabre\\\\HTTP\\\\Response"}]]},
{
"file":"/nextcloud/3rdparty/sabre/dav/lib/DAV/Server.php",
"line":254,
"function":"invokeMethod",
"class":"Sabre\\\\DAV\\\\Server",
"type":"->",
"args":
[
{
"absoluteUrl":"https://<NEXTCLOUD.DOMAIN>/remote.php/dav/uploads/<MY_USERNAME>/web-file-upload-<FILE_ID>/985661440",
"__class__":"Sabre\\\\HTTP\\\\Request"
},
{
"__class__":"Sabre\\\\HTTP\\\\Response"}
]
},
{
"file":"/nextcloud/apps/dav/lib/Server.php",
"line":319,
"function":"exec",
"class":"Sabre\\\\DAV\\\\Server","type":"->","args":[]},
{
"file":"/nextcloud/apps/dav/appinfo/v2/remote.php",
"line":35,
"function":"exec",
"class":"OCA\\\\DAV\\\\Server",
"type":"->","args":[]},
{"file":"/nextcloud/remote.php",
"line":165,"args":
[
"/nextcloud/apps/dav/appinfo/v2/remote.php"],
"function":"require_once"}
],
"File":"/nextcloud/apps/dav/lib/Connector/Sabre/File.php","Line":229,"CustomMessage":"--"}
```

Additional settings to try to avoid this issue in
*NEXTCLOUD/config/config.php:*

```
 'session_lifetime' => 60 * 60 * 24,
 'session_keepalive' => true,
```

Essential configs in
*php.ini*:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10G
php_value post_max_size 10G
php_value max_input_time 3600
php_value max_execution_time 3600
```